# Converting bootstrap menu to asp.net menu control

Tags: asp.net, menu

Although this question has been asked many times but I want to ask this again.
I want to convert the menu of the following bootstrap template to ASP.net menu control.

https://w3layouts.com/preview/?l=/smart-bazaar-e-commerce-shopping-category-bootstrap-responsive-web-template/

I am just placing part of the menu as below

```
<div class="w3ls-header-right">
    <ul>
        <li class="dropdown head-dpdn">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i> My Account<span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="login.html">Login </a></li> 
                <li><a href="signup.html">Sign Up</a></li> 
                <li><a href="login.html">My Orders</a></li>  
                <li><a href="login.html">Wallet</a></li> 
            </ul> 
        </li> 
    <ul>
<\div>
```

**ASP.NET menu control**

```
<ul>
    <li class="dropdown head-dpdn">         
        <asp:Menu ID="menu" runat="server" Orientation="Horizontal" CssClass="dropdown-toggle" >
            <Items>
                <asp:MenuItem Text="Products" Value="second">
                    <asp:MenuItem Text="IT Accessories" Value="IT Accessories" NavigateUrl="~/Product1.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
                    <asp:MenuItem Text="Clothes" Value="Clothes" NavigateUrl="~/Product2.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
                    <asp:MenuItem Text="Product 3" Value="Miscellaneous" NavigateUrl="~/Product3.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
                </asp:MenuItem>
                <asp:MenuItem Text="Products" Value="second"></asp:MenuItem>
                <asp:MenuItem Text="Products" Value="second"></asp:MenuItem>
                <asp:MenuItem Text="Products" Value="second"></asp:MenuItem>
                <asp:MenuItem Text="Products" Value="second"></asp:MenuItem>
            </Items>                            
        </asp:Menu>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Appologizing for not placing the code in proper format despite of my multiple efforts...

Kindly advise me regarding the solution of my problem...How can I used all those CSS in a particular order to accomplish the functionality.

Comment: Thanks...I tried multiple times but I don't know why that was sticking to not formatting properly.

Comment: We use a flavor of [Markdown](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax) for formatting our posts. It might be good for you to familiarize yourself with how that works, it's a pretty popular markup language.

Comment: Sure, I will learn by the time...

Comment: Menu controls have their own formatting, and it doesn't play well with mixing Bootstrap. Why do you want to switch to the Menu control?

Comment: I am more fluent on server side .